# Problem for import cloudgenix lib in views file on Django

Tags: django, import

Good morning,
As said in the title, I am facing a problem when want to import cloudgenix library into view file using Django framework.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import cloudgenix
```

My error : "Unable to resolve 'cloudgenix' importPylance reportMissingImports"

I hope someone can help me

I uninstall/install the library and i try to import on other files like models file